# Recommended stats to face Malthael

Tags: diablo-iii

Playing a Crusader, Torment 1 with mostly legendary gear.  What are all the recommended stats, and paragon level... to face Malthael again. I did see one recommended stat online as toughness of 4,000,000. Current toughness is 7,300,000 so I have that covered (I think). Are there any other recommended stats.

Comment: The only thing I found that seems to match Malthael damage is 2 elite packs. If you can handle 2 packs at the same time, you should be able to handle Malthael by staying careful enough to avoid the worst damage.

Comment: Defeated Malthael on Master with WD with 300k DPS and 7M Toughness. Was nervous, used one potion, but overall it went well. With Crusader's innate 30% reduction, you should be OK on Torment. Bring some Healing, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are playing hardcore, because if you are not playing hardcore... just try it.

You only have to answer one question:

- Can you kill Diablo at the same difficulty level?

If you can kill Diablo at the same difficulty level, you should be fine. Malthael has attacks that are very predictable and fairly easy to avoid. So, you should not be taking much damage anyways.

---

Also, not everything you do in Diablo should be decided based on the character sheet. The character sheet is very miss-leading as too how much damage you can take and how much damage you can do. The only time it is a good reflection of your capabilities is if you are a person that just stands in front of the creatures and holds your mouse buttons down. If you are actually doing complex builds and avoiding attacks and using abilities, the character sheet almost goes out the door and you have to base your opinion of your damage and toughness based on how things feel and your own personal calculations.